# Problems with the DbMigrator class and Entity Framework 5.0 update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-5

Hi I'm working in a MVC3 application and with Code First Migrations to manage my DB. Yesterday I just update my EF library to the 5.0 version. I used to ran in my Global.asax file, specifically in the method Application_Start(), so when the application starts the update-database command will run. It was something like this:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

But since the update I keep getting this exception, at the Migrator.Update() line.

[image]

I don't have any column with that name. I can understand this error. I check the Entity Framework 5.0 details and I didn't get any clue. And by the way If I run the Update-Database with the power-shell command prompt I don't get any error, my db updates correctly. Thanxs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your site doesn't use EF 5 because `CreatedOn` column was part of `__MigrationHistory` table (in system tables) in 4.3.1 but was removed in EF 5.

Comment: But why does this error start coming out when I updated? And why it doesn't come out when I run Update-Database trough the power sell prompt?

Comment: Because in powershell you are probably using EF 5 but at runtime you don't.

Comment: Well I made the update via Nuget. Let me check!. Thanxs Ladislav

Comment: I checked and the packages are correctly installed. Do you know why I could be using Ef 4.3 instead the 5.0?

Comment: No. It was just a quick idea because CreatedOn column was in that table before but it is not there in the last version and EF 5 automatically removes that column when it finds it (probably during `Update-Database` call).

Comment: Well on seconds thoughts @Ladislav I may be using a old version of EF. I'm in .Net 4.0, I haven't updated to the 4.5. So your quick idea couldn't be more accurate. And Update-Database did remove the CreatedOn Column.

Comment: We also came across this issue, ended up being due to us referencing an old version (2.0.3) of StackOverflow miniprofiler while using EF 5 for .NET 4.0.  Updating miniprofiler to version 2.10 resolved the issue

Comment: As far as I understand it EF5 check if the CreatedOn field still exist to drop it.

Comment: Actually updated to 2.10 didn't fix the issue, but it does appear to be miniprofiler related.